# re-execute / reload div code

Tags: php, javascript, html, refresh, reload

I got a php page with a grid that loads some info from a sql database, the code to connect to that database and execute the query is all inside a div, php code + html code. 
When the user selects one of the grid's row he can modify the values of the row, after that, the info on the grid has changed, and i am trying to reload that grid without reloading the whole page. Is there any way (javascript call or something) to reload/re-execute the code inside a especific div ??

thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, try searching for "Ajax"

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize your PHP function to get this div`s data, and use it after with Ajax request. PHP code are not bound to any div, its a HTML matter.

Answer (score 0):

No way from PHP...decouple the HTML page from PHP..Use ajax requests to extract the